# How get Tree in Model Activrecord Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have table

```
id | name          |pid
--------------------
1  | Cetegory1     | 0
--------------------
2  | SubCatregory1 | 1
--------------------
3  | SubCatregory2 | 1
--------------------
4  | Cetegory2     | 0
--------------------
5  | SubCatregory1 | 4
--------------------
6  | SubCatregory2 | 4
```

How select tree Categoryes from this table in ActeveRecord Rails3?

- Category 1

-- SubCategory 1

-- SubCategory 2

- Category 2

-- SubCategory 1

-- SubCategory 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On controller :

```
# select category with condition pid = 0
@categories = Category.where(:pid => 0)
```

On view :

```
<ul>
<% @categories.each do |c| %>

    <li><%= c.name %><li>
      # check if category not have subcategory 
      <% if Category.where(:pid => c.id ).empty? %>

      <% else %> 
       <dl>
        # select subcategory with condition pid = c.id
        <%  Category.where(:pid => c.id ).each do |sc| %>
         <dd>-- <%= sc.name %></dd>
        <% end %>
       </dl>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Result :

- Category 1

  -- SubCategory 1

  -- SubCategory 2
- Category 2
- Category 3

  -- SubCategory 1

  -- SubCategory 2